# Databricks-Salesforce connection

Tags: salesforce, azure-databricks, upsert

I want to upsert data into salesforce object using azure databricks. I have tried using the springml for salesforce but can't seem to establish a connection

I have tried installing the springml package from maven but still can't establish a connection.

Answer (score 0):

1.Connect with Salesforce you should download and install P DataDirect Salesforce JDBC Driver in local machine first.

2.You can download it from [here](https://www.progress.com/jdbc/salesforce)

3. To install the driver, you would have to execute the .jar package and you can do it by running the following command in terminal or just by double clicking on the jar package.
   java -jar PROGRESS_DATADIRECT_JDBC_SF_ALL.jar

It will install successfully to desired location.

You need to upload the jar fire into databricks to install the salesforce jdbc server.

1. Go to Clusters, select the cluster where you will be running the workloads. In that cluster, go to Libraries tab and Click on Install new. Select the Salesforce driver in the above path, click on Install to install the driver to that cluster as shown below.

[image]

Connecting to salesforce:

Open new notebook and check for jdbc server using below code:

```
Class.forName("com.ddtek.jdbc.sforce.SForceDriver")
```

Create JDBC URL for connecting to Salesforce using below code. Replace your username, password and Security Token (optional) in the below code.

```
val jdbcHostname ="login.salesforce.com"

val jdbcSecurityToken ="Your Security Token"

// Create the JDBC URL without passing in the user and password parameters.`

val jdbcUrl = s"jdbc:datadirect:sforce://${jdbcHostname};SecurityToken=${jdbcSecurityToken}"`

// Create a Properties() object to hold the parameters.`

import java.util.Properties

val connectionProperties =newProperties()

connectionProperties.put("user","Your username")

connectionProperties.put("password","Your password")
```

2. Set the driver class name by running the following command

   val driverClass = "com.ddtek.jdbc.sforce.SForceDriver"
   connectionProperties.setProperty("Driver",driverClass)
3. Now you can read the data from Salesforce by running the below code. Here is an example code to connect to Salesforce and print schema for Opportunity table.

   val opportunity_table = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, "Opportunity", connectionProperties)

   opportunity_table.printSchema

In this way you can connect to salesforce from azure databricks.

Reference Link: https://www.progress.com/tutorials/jdbc/connect-to-salesforce-from-azure-databricks